# Blender 3.3 Invalid UV Map with Hair Curve object

Tags: uv, hair, error

I was trying to use the new hair feature of Blender 3.3.

I duplicated and separated the scalp of my model (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> > <kbd>P</kbd>) and then added the Empty Hair object.

When I tried adding hair in Sculpt mode, I got the error `Missing UV map for attaching curves on original surface`, so I added a UV map named "UVMap".

I tried adding hair again, and now I have the error `Invalid UV map: UV islands must not overlap`.

I've tried unwrapping the UV map, but no luck there either...

Answer (score 2):

When you have an object selected and go to *Add mesh* > *Curves* > *Empty Hair*, what it does under the hood is:

1. add an empty curve object;
2. set it as child of the object you had selected;
3. add a Geometry node modifier on the curve object;
4. set up the curve data to use the selected object's surface and active UV map.

If your object don't have a UV map already done, you need to create it, then select the curve object, go to:
*Properties Editor* > *Curve Data tab* > *Surface Panel*
Write the name of the UV map you created. By default, it's `UVMap`.

Your UVs must have no overlap. There is no secret to this, select your mesh object, switch to *Edit mode*, and in the UV Editor, make sure all islands are not overlapping and have a bit of space between each other:

[image: demo UV]

After that, you should be able to select the curve object and switch to the *sculpt mode* to do your hair.