# Can not add new curve hairs on geo-node hair (3.5), Invalid surface UVs

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair

I made geo-node curves from a mesh (mesh, convert to bezier curves, convert to geo-node curves) and I can't seem to add any new hairs on it in brush mode now that it's been converted.

New empty curves come with a few things listed here [Blender 3.3 Invalid UV Map with Hair Curve object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274145/blender-3-3-invalid-uv-map-with-hair-curve-object)
(parented to object, has a geo node for the surface deform)
and I made sure to recreate those as well, but it seems to still not be working properly.

[image]

It also gives "Invalid surface UVs on 82 curves" error under Surface Deform. It doesn't have "surface_uv_coordinate" at all which I believe might be part of it.
It's been unwrapped, the UV also isn't overlapping, and as well the faces are all facing out.

Below is the project file. I would appreciate some guidance, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Invalid surface UVs on 82 curves" has not been fixed, but was ultimately throwing me off. I'm still not certain how to fix it or what it is, but I was able to add more curves

Seeing "Path11 Media" answer and "density" brush working made me realize I was focusing too much on it, and not the brush itself.

The problem lied in the curve interpolation. Due to it not having enough curves to interpolate between, adding hair on certain parts of the mesh would make it just not exist.

[image]

Disabling shape interpolation had helped fix the problem, however it will only interpolate properly if I add more hair guides for it to blend with.

Answer (score 1):

I just now found that issue on mine, I don't know if it is a bug or what. I think it is a bug. I went out of my job, opened a new one and divided the basic cube up then started to add hair, everything fine so far. Then, I went to Edit mode, moved one point on one hair and all the hair tools were disassociated with the hair and none of them would function with everything I had put in up to that point (luckily I learned to save my progressions as different named jobs). Also, whenever I had the UVmap disassociation error I noticed in the curves tab my UVMap wasn't correct so I reset it but, yours looks correct on that which leads me to think that any edit unhooks the hair sculpt tools.

Update: I started a fresh job, left the cube and duplicated it and pulled to the side. Added a few hairs on each and all sculpt tools work fine. Went to one hair on the first cude, edit mode for the hair, moved one point and sure enough, all sculpt tools for the hairs I put on were disconnected and unusable for the hairs on that cube. On the same cube I added fresh hairs just below the originals and those allowed me to comb and sculpt but the ones I had previously added and edited above them would not. In the object tree, it was still one set of curves yet the first ones (top rows) are not touchable and have no curve to manipulate like the ones below that hadn't been manipulated. [image]

So, if anything is done to the curve, it quits being a hair curve apparently

Now I went back to yours and couldn't add hair...then noticed that your selection was set to points, I couldn't add any hair (I'm using 3.5.1). [image]

I switched it to curves and it let me add hair. [image]

Comment: Thank you! This does seem to help out quite a bit. It didn't fully fix it, but this gave me a ton more insight as to how I can fix it.

It still didn't work when I added curves using the add tool. I realized it seems when I enable interpolation on the curves (as well as on density) it makes it disappear.

The error regarding the surface UV was throwing me off, the issue lies in how the interpolation works and how it has a lack of guides. It is odd to me you weren't able to add more curves in in point mode though, as I was able to somehow...?